# Understanding simple php code

Tags: php, mysql

My boss recently asked me to fix some PHP code, but that's not my usual task and I have a few problems in understanding the original code.

So, this is what I got:

```
//$query is set here
if ($result = mysql_query($query, $db)) {
  $number = mysql_num_rows($result);
  if ($number == 0) {
    echo 'Error!';
  }
  else {
    // do something
  }
} // etc
```

I'm not sure that the first line of code does something.
Why did he write it like that? I think it will always enter the first 'if' condition no matter what, am I correct?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there is an error the function `mysql_query` will return `FALSE`. So, think of that like `if($result = 5/0) { /* will not pass because of division by zero */ }`

Comment: @enenen Not a good analogy, since that will fail for different reasons than a simple return of `false`.

Comment: @deceze yes, you are right, of course.

Answer (score 3):

> I think it will always enter the first 'if' condition no matter what, am I correct?

No. The return value of `mysql_query` will be assigned to `$result`. That value will then be tested for truthyness.

If there are any errors with the query, then it will be false.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($result = mysql_query($query, $db)) {
```

This is checking if `$result` will return true so we can proceed, `$return` is just an execution of query to the database using `mysql_query` command and passing as variables both  query `$query` itself and connection parameters `$db`. If this will return false it will mean there are errors in the query

I would rather point you attention on `mysql_query` functions wich you are using. They are deprecated and no longer manteined, so you better learn about either [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Thank you. Yes we're planning on moving to mysqli soon, this was just about a small fix on very simple instructions.

Answer (score 1):

```
//$query is set here
if ($result = mysql_query($query, $db)) {
```

This part of the code declares what the database query is supposed to be, and tries to run it.  `myssql_query` runs a request for data (or tries to put data) into the database, but it might not be formatted correctly, or the database might have an error, or it might be on a different server and that server is down, or perhaps there's a problem with the data not matching limitations on the data that the database is connecting.

In any case, it tries to request data from the database, and put that data into `$result`.  BUT - if there is a problem putting data into the database, then it doesn't have any data to put into `$result`, and the `if` statement will see it as false, not entering into that first if loop.

```
    $number = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($number == 0) {
```

In a way, this is doing something similar.  The previous programmer is basically declaring that no matter what happens, the `$query` database request for data (or inputting data) should return at least one row of data, no matter what.  If everything seems to be running fine, the server is running, the database is running, and the query isn't rejected ... but no lines of data are returned ... then there's still something wrong.  Perhaps a logic error in the code, perhaps some poorly formatted data in a user-inputted field, who knows?  But in any case, if nothing returns, he wants to signify that something is very wrong here.

Comment: Glad to help someone understand.  We've all been there.